# How to convert Stellar Lumens into USD

Tags: stellar

I have created Stellar account. I have to transfer lumens to other account in USD.
How can I convert lumens to USD?

On stellar site, it is mentioned that we have create trust line with provided Anchors. But while creating thrust line it is always saying "changeTrustLowReserve".

Please suggest any inputs if you have.

Answer (score -1):

What I'd suggest is to convert it to USDT on [Bittrex](https://bittrex.com) or [Bitfinex](https://www.bitfinex.com/) and then proceed to withdraw USDT to your bank account.

Another alternative is to convert it to BTC and withdraw it in cash using [Localbitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/).

Answer (score -1):

There aren't many exchanges at this time where you can directly sell Lumens for USD.
However, quite a few exchanges exist where you can buy Lumens for other cryptocoins.

For now, I believe a two-step process is required:

1. Trade your Lumens for a better-known crypto coin, like Bitcoin, on one of these exchanges: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/stellar/#markets
2. Transfer those Bitcoins to a well-known exchange that will trade Bitcoin for USD. Coinbase is an obvious example.

As it stands right now, none of this is particularly easy. It can be a bit nerve racking, and cost you quite a bit in transfer fees. 
Just so you know ahead of time what to expect :-)

Answer (score -1):

[Coinbase Pro](https://pro.coinbase.com/trade/XLM-USD) is probably your best choice to convert XLM directly to USD.